# Is the way to get users device OS version and ip address for android?

Tags: java, android, json, operating-system, ip

I'm creating **android app** and want to get, in the backend, authenticated user's device **OS version** and the **ip address**? after some researches, I didn't found the helpful information and can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's in java
For OsVesion:

```
  String osVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " " + Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].getName();
```

For IP: if it's mobileData

```
    public static String getMobileIPAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return addr.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

For IP: if it's WiFi

```
public String getWifiIPAddress() {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    return Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
}
```

to check if it's mobile data or WiFi:

```
            if (getWifiIPAddress().equals("0.0.0.0")) {
                ipAddress = getMobileIPAddress();
            } else {
                ipAddress = getWifiIPAddress();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get **os version** with:

```
val deviceOS = android.os.Build.VERSION;
```

for **ip address**:

```
fun getLocalIpAddress(): String? {
    try {
        val en: Enumeration<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            val networkInterface: NetworkInterface = en.nextElement()
            val enumerationIpAddress: Enumeration<InetAddress> = networkInterface.inetAddresses
            while (enumerationIpAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                val inetAddress: InetAddress = enumerationIpAddress.nextElement()
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress && inetAddress is Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: SocketException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: As I guess, it's Kotlin. I'm using java.

Comment: you can convert it into java. @T.Kopa